# ubuntu 1604 - sound card ALC892 - no surround (5.1) thru HDMI output - only after wake up from sleep

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, realtek

i had sound card realtek ALC 892 on asrock j3455 itx but i cannot get sound from rear speakers thru HDMI cable but with stereo it wowrking fine. I did try many:

- install pavu, alsamixer, turnoff on any devices oupts ....
- also `https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS`
- edit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf with plenty of options

onyl this was looking as somethhing real `https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1236` but i end up on command ./configure...  becasue script was not able to find kerenel file o version

strange is that after many many hours I did find that if i put ubuntu in sleep modeand tahn wake up it works as 5.1 thru HDMI not only stereo.

before this it show that rear speakers are playing sound but no sound comming also my onkyo was not showing 5 spkears only 2. I need to mention that there is KODI runing on this machine.

thanks for any ideas.